# React HOC can't pass props?

Tags: reactjs

I tried to pass `description=Button` props to `Button` Component using HOC.
so that, I expected to render like, `Button

But, Empty Button Elements is Rendered!

My codeSandBoxLink:[enter link description here](https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-haze-qtygh6?file=/src/withloading.jsx)

Button.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import withLoading from './withLoading'

function Button() {
    return <button></button>
}
export default withLoading(Button)
```

withLoading.jsx

```
export default function withLoading(Component) {
  const WithLoadingComponent = (props) => {
    return <Component>{props.description}</Component>
    );
  };

  return WithLoadingComponent;
```

App.jsx

```
return(
 <div>
    <Button description="button"><Button>
 </div>
)
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You must provide a [mcve] here

Comment: whats your export from `withLoading.jsx` file?

Comment: I export withLoading Function!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At `Button` compnent, you need to use `props` and follow your code so that is `props.description`.

```
function Button(props) {
  return <button>{props.description}</button>;
}
```

At `withLoading` HOC, you need to pass all `props` for `Component`.

```
//HOC Example
export default function withLoading(Component) {
  const WithLoadingComponent = (props) => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);
    console.log("props:", props.description);
    //delay 3sec...
    React.useEffect(() => {
      const timer = setTimeout(() => {
        setLoading(false);
      }, 3000);
      return () => clearTimeout(timer);
    }, []);

    return loading ? <p>loading...</p> : <Component {...props} />;
  };

  return WithLoadingComponent;
}
```

---

I have been `fork` and then fixed it. You can refer by `this link`:  https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-cerf-glxquu?file=/src/withLoading.jsx

Comment: Should not post code as images. When you make an edit with the code I’ll remove my downvote.

Comment: I edited my answer, Thanks of your advice. @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ

Comment: Thanks!  i confused with using props...!  Thank for help!